# javascript: json object with arrays serialized for use in .NET MVC action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, json, jquery

simple question:

I want to post some data to an action like this:

```
        var data = {
            Prop1 : 'a',
            ListOfObjects: [{ PropertyA: 1, PropertyB: 2 }, { PropertyA: 3, PropertyB: 4}]
        };
```

When I send this data to my Action via JQuery AJAX, my model is partially filled:

```
public class MyObject{
    public int PropertyA {get;set;}
    public int PropertyB {get;set;}
}

public class MyModel{
    public string Prop1 {get;set;}
    public List<MyObject> ListOfObjects {get;set;}
}

public JsonResult Save(MyModel model)
.
.
.
model.Prop1 //Is okay!
model.ListOfObjects[0] // is okay too...List has 2 items
model.ListOfObjects[0].PropertyA; //Nope...no values inside this model...
```

I guess the reason is, that the serialized HTTP Data are wrong, they are like
ListOfObjects[0][PropertyA] <- but it should be ListOfObjkects[0].PropertyA

Does anyone know what to do?!

EDIT:
My JQuery AJAX code:

```
$.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: saveURL,
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: data,
                    complete: function () {
                        DeleteMainLoader();
                    },
                    success: function success(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                        if (data.success) {
                            alert('win!')
                        }
                        else {
                            alert('error');
                        }

                    },
                    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert('errrrrooooorrrr');
                    }
                });
```

Comment: did you miss the comma after 'a'?

Comment: can post your jquery ajax code ?

Comment: Yeah thanks, I missed a "," but not in my code :) I typed all this outta my mind, because I was at work at this time. I edited my first post and added my jquery ajax call i used

Comment: How is the data you are posting serialized? I'll try something like: $.ajax({ ... data: JSON.stringify(your_js_object)});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using ASP.NET MVC 3 or later, the easiest thing to do there is to send JSON instead of URL encoded data. That makes complex, nested objects a lot easier to work with since jQuery doesn't need to understand any of ASP.NET MVC's conventions at that point.

To do that, just build up an object matching your server-side class, stringify it, and be sure to set a content type of `application/json` on the request:

```
var data = {
  Prop1 : 'a',
  ListOfObjects: [{ PropertyA: 1, PropertyB: 2 }, { PropertyA: 3, PropertyB: 4}]
};

$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: saveURL,
  // This is unnecessary; jQuery will detect the response's dataType based
  //  on its Content-Type header automatically.
  dataType: 'json',
  // This sets the request's Content-Type to let MVC know how to interpret the
  //  data parameter.
  contentType: 'application/json',
  // I can't remember if this is 100% necessary in this case, but some ASP.NET 
  //  endpoints only work if you match up the method's parameter name like this.
  data: JSON.stringify({ model: data })
});
```

Comment: wow thanks! This works like a charm :D And yes I have to use model : data ... otherwise I get a server error.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, I guess your problem is because you are sending a js object, instead of a proper json.

```
var data = {
            Prop1 : 'a',
            ListOfObjects: [{ PropertyA: 1, PropertyB: 2 }, { PropertyA: 3, PropertyB: 4}]
           };

$.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: saveURL,
         dataType: 'json',
         data: JSON.stringify(data),
         // rest of the code         
      });
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your answer, but this didn't work. Dave Ward's answer works fine. The contentType was missing.